# angular phonecat - change http servers port

Tags: angularjs, httpserver

Im trying to run the phone-cat application on a separate port than 8000.
Reason being im already running something on that port.

I ask because I took an quick look around and the answer doesn't seem to be trivial.

Commands to find the location of this attribute are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the following line in the package.json of your phonecat folder:

"start": "http-server -p 8000".

Replace 8000 for the port of your choice.

Comment: Yup, that is exactly correct. I found this after I posted the question.

Comment: Just some clarification, the section would look similar to this:

    "scripts": {
        "start": "http-server -p 8000",
        ...<more>...
    },

I'm adding this because my project (not phonecat) had two "package.json" files in it.  Mine was under bower_components/boostrap.